# React Native: Command `run-ios` unrecognized

Tags: react-native

I have two different ReactNative-Projects:

- a) a project from januar 2016
- b) a complete new react-native project
  from now (march 20th 2016)

Within the new project the cli tool of react-native contains the command "run-ios" next two "run-android", but not on the older project from januar 2016. On the older one there is not "run-ios" command available:

```
$ react-native run-ios
Command `run-ios` unrecognized
Usage: react-native <command>
```

I already ran "react-native upgrade" without any issues.

How can i get the command "run-ios" also in older projects?

Comment: If you're like me and you tried `npx react-native run-ios`, make sure you are actually inside the project folder..

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Just update the version of react native in your project with the following command:

```
$> npm install --save react-native@latest
```

Comment: Yeah that broke 3 other things for me. Now I'm trying to downgrade.

Answer (score 43):

What caused this for me was running `npm install --save [package]` when actually the system has previously been using `yarn` instead of `npm`.

To solve this I just deleted the `node_modules` folder and ran: `yarn install` and after that `react-native run-ios` (or android) works fine.

Comment: Had the same mf issue :D, why does yarn conflict with npm though?

Answer (score 35):

```
 $ react-native run-ios
```

**If you get this kinda error:**

> "Command `run-ios` unrecognized. Make sure that you have run `npm
>   install` and that you are inside a react-native project".

In terminal, make sure you are inside a react-native project directory.

Execute this cmd:

```
$ react-native -v
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: n/a - not inside a React Native project directory
$ npm update
$ react-native -v
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.44.0
$ react-native run-ios
```

Comment: What does it mean to be in a "React Native project directory"? What file does it look for?

Comment: @PetrusTheron In terminal, you should be on the root folder of the path where you have created the project.

Comment: Being in the react-native directory did it for me! I was in ios.

Answer (score 26):

This may sound silly, but make sure you cd to your project directory. If that fails then perform the npm install in the other answers.

Answer (score 6):

I found a solution that works for me. 
Update the version of react native in your project:

```
npm install --save react-native@latest
```

then upgrade your npm version

```
npm i npm@latest -g
```

then move directory folder 1 level up, type

```
cd ..
```

make a new react-native installation folder

```
react-native init NewProject
```

then go to your project folder(NewProject), after that

```
react-native run-ios
```

should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

This happens when the project has an older version of react native. You can update the react version or for people who do not want to upgrade, just open the .xcodeproj file in iOS dir and hit the play button in the Xcode.

Comment: why would you post the same answer?

Comment: @csomakk there is second part to the answer too.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was an issue with the package.json file. I deleted a section during a test. I recover a previous file with the deleted section and everything was working again.

Comment: aha I left a comma in my package.json and that solved the issue!

Answer (score 1):

this works for me

```
sudo npm install -g react-native-cli --force
```

then

```
react-native run-ios
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I am using **monorepo** with multiple packages in a single repo. I solved this error by

- Deleting the `packages/myapp/node_modules`
- running `yarn install` from the project root. Not inside packages
- its solved. Now can run `yarn ios` or `yarn android` commands

**Note:**
For autolinking libraries you need to have all of your dependencies in root `package.json` file also copied to `packages/myapp/package.json` file. See https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/autolinking.md#how-can-i-use-autolinking-in-a-monorepo

Example:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^3.5.2",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.5",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.6.0",
    "@voximplant/react-native-foreground-service": "^2.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.18.2",
    ...
    ...
```

but make sure NOT TO COPY

```
    "react-native-cli": "^any version",
```

otherwise `react-native-cli` would collide and you will continue to see error like

```
Command `run-android` unrecognized. Make sure that you have run `npm install` and that you are inside a react-native project.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

or

```
Command `run-ios` unrecognized. Make sure that you have run `npm install` and that you are inside a react-native project.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: Works great. Could you explain why react-native-cli needs to be in the root package.json?

Answer (score 0):

I created a brand new react-native project using
`$ react-native init projectName`
and ran from root of the project
`$ react-native run-ios`
Everything worked fine and iOS simulator fired up as expected.

Than I installed `prop-types` node module using `npm install prop-types --save`. Re-ran `$ react-native run-ios` and ran into this error **Command run-ios unrecognized**

**Solution:** 
From the root of my project, removed `node_module` and re-installed modules using npm. Commands below

```
$ rm -rf node_modules/
$ npm install
$ react-native run-ios
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, Xcode was already running.

Close the Xcode and then in the terminal, make sure you are inside a react-native project directory and then execute **react-native run-ios** command

Answer (score 0):

For me, the only thing that worked was to checkout again my repository from zero and run:

```
npm install -g react-native-cli yarn 
yarn  
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Answer (score 0):

What caused this for me was running `npm install --save axios` when actually the system was previously using `yarn` instead of `npm`.

To solve this, instead of deleting the `node_modules` folder, which can lead to more problems, and if you prefer to run `npm` anyway or don't have a preference either way, the error should have instructed for you to run `npm install`. If you literally follow those instructions, you will be able to run: `react-native run-ios` afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I also fell in this error and the reason was
I was using `yarn link` command in wrong folder

Answer (score 0):

Delete the node-modules. Its because the packages are not installed.

`rm -rf node_modules
 npm install`

then run your project

`react-native run-ios`