# react-native run-android is unrecognized

Tags: android, node.js, react-native

I've installed react-native-cli globally:

```
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

Then run:

```
react-native init AwesomeProject
cd AwesomeProject
```

I got the following structure:

```
-- AwesomeProject   
---- node_modules      
------ react-native
```

When I run *react-native run-android* I get an error:
**Command `run-android` unrecognized. Did you mean to run this inside a react-native project?**

When I run react-native start I get the same.

`react-native -v`
prints:
**react-native-cli: 0.2.0

react-native: n/a - not inside a React Native project directory**

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: cd into AwesomeProject then run react-native --version

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem was that I terminated **init** command because it looked like hanged without errors (even 24 hours later). To fix this I updated nodejs and npm to newer versions. Once I have done it **react-native init** was executed properly and there is no more problem with **react-native run-android**.

Comment: After trying different solutions this one worked for me thank you :)

Answer (score 74):

the answer is easy nad it is not because of any bug at all.

```
make sure you are in correct directory
```

if in current directory there is not any react native app ,it gives you this error

Comment: XD caught me off guard

Comment: yup, this was definitely the issue

Comment: lol good to see number of upvotes and know I'm not alone xD thanks!

Comment: Yes, please watch your project structure if you face this issue. I cloned https://github.com/liplylie/react-native-simple-alarm, made `npm install` and tried to run `npx react-native run-android` like we usually do for  other simple apps available on github. It gave error command run-android not found. But following this answer I watched the project, had to navigate to example folder.
In example folder, command run-android worked as expected.

Answer (score 54):

What caused this for me was running `npm install --save [package]` when actually the system has previously been using `yarn` instead of `npm`.

To solve this I just deleted the `node_modules` folder and ran: `yarn install` and after that `react-native run-ios` (or android) works fine.

(This is a duplicate of [React Native: Command `run-ios` unrecognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36119358/react-native-command-run-ios-unrecognized/44851272#44851272))

Comment: Honestly, react-native would be an impossible platform if Stack Overflow didn't exist. Thank you.

Answer (score 32):

I just ran "yarn" with no arguments and it fixed it.

Comment: @sergey-onishchenko This should be the answer ... I usually clone a react-native project and run it before installing dependencies.

Answer (score 28):

Please try this command:

```
npm install --save react-native
```

Comment: I comment this to remember which command use to solve this problem if happens for a third time, thanks this works for me :)

Comment: This did the trick for me. I had some errors and deleted my `package.json` file and `node_modules` directory and for some reason `$ npm install` wasn't doing anything. This command did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

> react-native run-android is unrecognized

Make sure that you have installed npm or use 
in your project directory

```
npm install
```

Answer (score 7):

you have to update your npm.
To do that

```
npm install npm@latest -g
```

Answer (score 7):

This can be caused by a couple of issues.

**!!! Before trying each solution remember to open a new terminal since you might have old paths sources from your .bashrc file. !!!**

1. **You did not install the contents of the project**. In order to solve this you have to install the node_modules by typing:

   `npm install or yarn install`
2. **You are coming back to a previously installed project after doing some funny things with your react-native installation and global configurations**. (Upgrading the library, upgrading node doing something with globally installed node_modules).

You should clean all your caches and project modules

Here you can find a command to do all these things in one line (remember to replace npm with yarn accordingly):
https://gist.github.com/jarretmoses/c2e4786fd342b3444f3bc6beff32098d

3. **Your global installation of react-native or react-native-cli is broken**. In this case simply reinstall your libraries globally.

   npm: `npm install -g react-native && npm install -g @react-native-community/cli`

   yarn: `yarn global add react-native && yarn global add @react-native-community/cli`

Comment: it worked for me!

Comment: Awesome! :D Happy to help! :D

Answer (score 6):

try "yarn install".
It will install the missing files in node_modules

It worked for me

Answer (score 5):

I think the command you are looking for is react-native run-android.

cd into your project and run this command where all you js files are present and not in the android folder.

It will run a package manager, do not close that. Also you need to have an emulator or a device connected to your computer with usb debugging enabled.

Hope the answer helped

Comment: react-native run-android  - that is the command that I have used. And I did it from within AwesomeProject directory.

Comment: hmmmm could you do a  ls in that directory and post the results. Also are you sure that the init got completed without any issues?

Comment: I have terminated the execution of the init because It looked like it finished it's job. I will try it again. Actually, should it take so long?

Comment: First time it takes long enough to feel like nothing is happening Ideally you'll get a index.android.js and index.ios.js and other such files let it run to completion go out for a walk and then try again!

Answer (score 5):

You can solve this by yarn or npx:

```
yarn react-native run-android
npx react-native run-android
```

Answer (score 5):

Do `npm install` then run `react-native run-android`

Answer (score 5):

Step 01 : Make sure that you are in right directory
Step 02 : `npm install` run this command
Step 03 : `npm audit fix` run this to fix issues

Try deleting `node_modules` folder and then run the commands again

Answer (score 4):

```
npx react-native run-android
```

Use of npx will pick local npm node_modules directory

Comment: I tried this.... same error for me error Unrecognized command "run-android".

Comment: the error was resolved after running npm install --save react-native as explained in another answer below

Answer (score 3):

- Make sure you go into the directory having package.json
- If you have deleted nodemodules try "npm install".
- And don't forget the "init" in "react-native init MyApp". "init"
  initializes the package.json.

Answer (score 2):

Everything has already tried like me? Then try again once "Yarn install after deleting node_modules". It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I did everything correct while setting up, but was unable to run the android code. Just make sure while running the command `react-native run-android` that, you are inside the AwesomeProject folder created by the `react-native init AwesomeProject` command.

The folder by default for my PC was under `C:\Windows\system32\AwesomeProject` in Windows.

Hope it helped for the first timers :)

Comment: Oh Maybe! But for me this worked just fine. Keep digging!

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the project with the latest version of react-native. Just run this command.

`npm install --save react-native@latest`

Answer (score 1):

If you guys have latest react native version and facing this error

> "UNRECOGNIZED COMMAND run-android".

then run follow these steps it will definitely help you.

Step: 1 -> create a new file "`react-native.config.js`" in the project root directory.

Step : 2 -> Inside "`package.json`" you have "`assets`" array inside "`rnpm`" object cut these assets from this and paste in your "react-`native.config.js`".
i-e:

```js
module.exports = {
assets: ['./assets/fonts'],
}
```

Step : 3 -> Remove "`rnpm`" object from "`package.json`".

Step : 4 -> Replace your "scripts" with below mentioned "scripts" inside "`package.json`"

```js
"scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest",
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "android:prod": "npx react-native run-android --variant=release",
    "ios:prod": "react-native run-ios --configuration Release"
  }
```

That's it
Happy Hacking..............

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I forgot to run `npm install` before running `react-native run-android`. I know this is a silly mistake but it may help.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall `react-native` from global

```
$ npm uninstall -g react-native
```

Then

Install `react-native` to global

```
$ npm install -g react-native-cli
```

Answer (score 0):

That worked for me

```
react-native run-android


 start [options]                    starts the webserver
run-ios [options]                  builds your app and starts it on iOS simulator
run-android [options]              builds your app and starts it on a connected Android emulator or device
new-library [options]              generates a native library bridge
bundle [options]                   builds the javascript bundle for offline use
unbundle [options]                 builds javascript as "unbundle" for offline use
eject [options]                    Re-create the iOS and Android folders and native code
link [options] [packageName]       links all native dependencies (updates native build files)
unlink [options] <packageName>     unlink native dependency
install [options] <packageName>    install and link native dependencies
uninstall [options] <packageName>  uninstall and unlink native dependencies
upgrade [options]                  upgrade your app's template files to the latest version; run this after updating the react-native version in your package.json and running npm install
log-android [options]              starts adb logcat
log-ios [options]                  starts iOS device syslog tail
dependencies [options]             lists dependencies
info [options]                     Get relevant version info about OS, toolchain and libraries
```

They have made some unnoticeable changes. **For instance run-android(now) run android(before).**

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete "package-lock.json" and re-run "npm install", then try your command, It should work

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because I had parenthesis in the path "(" and ")". Possibly this error is thrown for other special characters as well.

Comment: In which path? In which file?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you run the command in the projects' terminal, preferably the Android IDE. Run the `adb devices` to know your active devices as well

Answer (score 0):

If your `package.json` file is containing any comment then this error is comes. So remove all comments from `package.json` and then run command it will work.

Also try to run command `npm install --save` then it will log if other error there. If any others error also there, then first fix it and then run command it will work.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio click in Tools -> SDK Manager -> in System Settings click in Android SDK -> choose tab SDK Tools, then enable Android SDK command line tools (lasted).
It work for me!

Answer (score 0):

Open your React Native Project Root Directory and locate `android -> app -> build -> intermediates -> signing_config -> debug -> out -> signing-config.json`

Delete `signing-config.json` file

And rebuild your application.

```
react-native run-android
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to delete node_mouldes and package.lock.json and do yarn install after that if you're using Windows OS  you need to use PowerShell not git bash and write this command "react-native run-android"

Answer (score 0):

Install npm again to latest
react-native init project_name
cd project_name
open android studio the same android folder inside your project_name
react_native run_android
will work now

Answer (score 0):

for the last time your project was working fine and now you got this error suddenly and you have **Node modules already installed** then just try`npm install --save react-native`
this work for me

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there was an extra comma in the Package.json in the "dependencies" section.
"use-is-mounted-ref": "^1.4.0",

This made react to not be able to update, install anything.
Last line shouldn't have any comma

Answer (score 0):

I got this because I accidentally installed a react template and not a react-native template

Answer (score -1):

For my case, I just forgot to access the project folder using "cd" command after generating the project.

Comment: You can comment on question same, instead of posting new answer.

Answer (score -1):

I forgot to change the directory first after run react-native init command.
When I ran command inside the react-native project directory it worked
post that run the command npx react-native run-ios or run-andoid, it will work.

```
error Unrecognized command "run-android". info Run "react-native --help" to see a list of all available commands.
```

Answer (score -1):

First, ensure you have configured environment variables correctly.
If yes, then make sure Powershell/cmd runs in the project's directory and node js is configured correctly.

Answer (score -2):

Okay, I tried many of the tough solutions, also many mentioned above, But yarn install did the job greatly.

> `yarn install`

Answer (score -3):

Firstly you have run cmd line as a **admin** before enter "npx react-native init <your_project_name>" command. Then try other solutions.

Comment: what do you exactly mean bu admin? user needs to navigateto project root folder and run npm run command or react-native cli command