# Getting error - Unrecognized command "run-android", when running react native,

Tags: android, react-native

I get this error when try and run react native on my emulator, `react-native run-android`

> error Unrecognized command "run-android".

My emulator is connected and working, any ideas?

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "iaapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "name": "Inovative Anatomy",
    "flow": "flow",
    "test": "node ./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --watchAll"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.4.4",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.6.1",
    "react": "16.8.5",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-native": "0.59.10",
    "react-native-circular-progress": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-component-fade": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-fade": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-fade-in-view": "^1.0.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-responsive-image": "^2.3.1",
    "react-native-share": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^9.5.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-native-view-shot": "^2.6.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^5.12.1",
    "react-native-webview-bridge": "^0.40.1",
    "react-navigation": "^3.0.9",
    "react-navigation-backhandler": "^1.3.2",
    "react-navigation-transitions": "^1.0.11",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-persist": "^5.10.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.8.4",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.7",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.18",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.2",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.60.14",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.7",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^16.9.0",
    "@types/redux-logger": "^3.0.7",
    "@types/redux-persist": "^4.3.1",
    "babel-jest": "^24.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "jest": "^24.1.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.54.1",
    "prettier": "^1.18.2",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^0.2.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.6",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "tslint-react": "^4.2.0",
    "typescript": "^3.6.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [react-native run-android is unrecognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37612660/react-native-run-android-is-unrecognized)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `npx react-native run-android`

Comment: you probably using @react-native-community/cli, please check https://github.com/react-native-community/cli#about

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue for a few minutes until I realized I was running the command in the wrong directory...

I'm putting this here in hopes that this will help some future dev from making a similar, simple, mistake.

Comment: What is the wrong directory? The right one?

Comment: The correct directory is the root of the project. The wrong directory is any other location

Answer (score 0):

if `npx react-native run-android` is not working goto `package.json` file
and look over "scripts" debugger is there.
clicking on debugger gives you options on top of the screen.
select `react-native run-android`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your npm version... Use this command and try again...

```
npm install npm@latest -g
```

credits [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44322576/3976388)