# Cannot run "npx react-native run-android": Unrecognized command "run-android"

Tags: react-native, android-studio

I am trying to open an app via Android Studio. I have previously used Expo as my React Native development environment, but this app uses the React Native CLI. I have followed all of the instructions for the CLI setup here:
https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

However, when I finally try to run "npx react-native run-android", something strange happens. The terminal starts chewing metadata and stuff as if it received my command, but then after a while it finishes with the text:

error Unrecognized command "run-android".
info Run "react-native --help" to see a list of all available commands.

A few observations:

- Running "react-native --help" also returns an error, because it "is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program."
- After the chewing of metadata but before the error, there are many lines of codes with warnings, which all look like this (regarding a variety of libraries):

warn Package @react-native-community/eslint-config has been ignored because it contains invalid configuration. Reason: Cannot find module '@react-native-community\eslint-config\package.json'

- The developer said I did not need to install any particular libraries or modules - perhaps he was wrong? Still doesn't solve the issue though.
- I have tried writing the same commands in different terminals, but the result is the same.
- I have tried using the terminal debugger in Visual Studio code as suggested in the thread below, but that did not make me any wiser.
  [Getting error - Unrecognized command "run-android", when running react native,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60319124/getting-error-unrecognized-command-run-android-when-running-react-native)

Comment: maybe try "npx react-native run-android" <-- with a space instead of a -

Comment: It does not recognize either the command "react" or the command "run".

Comment: I have edited my post now, at first it said that I used the command "npx-react-native run-android", but what I meant was "npx react-native run-android", without a dash between react and native. THAT is when it returns: Unrecognized command "run-android". Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Run `npm install` first. That will install the missing modules it is complaining about. Then run `npx react-native run-android`

Answer (score 0):

Try `npm install` or hover over the "android" command in package.json file and then click on **Run Script** it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same problem recently. In my case I had not installed dependencies. Running
**npm install** worked in my case