# Detect development environment in react-native.config.js

Tags: react-native

I want to access `__DEV__` in `react-native.config.js` so I can manage some native libraries linking in the development & production environments like sample bellow:

```
const VECTOR_ICONS_FONTS_PATH =
  './node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts';
const VECTOR_FONTS = ['MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf'];

module.exports = {
  assets: ['./src/assets/fonts/nop/nop.ttf'],
  dependencies: {
    'react-native-vector-icons': {
      platforms: {
        ios: null,
        android: null,
      },
      assets: VECTOR_FONTS.map((font) => VECTOR_ICONS_FONTS_PATH + '/' + font),
    },
    'react-native-flipper': {
      platforms: {
        ios: null,
        android: __DEV__ ? undefined : null,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

But if I do this I get the following error:

```
$ react-native run-android
error Unrecognized command "run-android".
info Run "react-native --help" to see a list of all available commands.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: try `npm run android` if the error is same then it may be due to node_modules, try deleting node_modules and package-lock.json and then do `npm install` and try again your command

Comment: I'm not using npm. @shubhamjha & it's not the solution.

Comment: what are you using then ? could you post your package.json file?

Comment: Create two separate files `staging` and `production`. Then write a script that copy one of these files based on argument that you pass, then override your main `config` file. This is what I am doing, Let me know if you have better solution please.

Answer (score -1):

What version of Nodejs and NPM are you using?

This can sometimes happen when the project is not initialized properly.
Perhaps try the following:

1. Update NodeJs/NPM if not LTS
2. Delete the node_modules directory
3. Run `npm install or yarn install`
4. Run `react-native init`
5. Run `react-native run-android`

(Duplicate of [react-native run-android is unrecognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37612660/react-native-run-android-is-unrecognized))