# Beset with errors trying getting started with react-native.

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm new to react, and I'm having a lot of trouble getting started. Here's a list of errors I run into in sequence:

1. Run `npm install` on a package, then `react-native run-ios`. Then error:

`Command 'run-ios' unrecognized. Make sure that you have run 'npm install' and that you are inside a react-native project.`

2. Run install the latest react-native (according to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36119358/react-native-command-run-ios-unrecognized)), which solves the problem.
3. Rerun the simulator. Error:

`Cannot find entry file index.ios.js in any of the roots: ["/Users/Dan/ReactApp/node_modules/react-native/packager"`

4. Run `kill -9 (process Id of server on 8081) && npm start` (according to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29388704/react-cannot-find-entry-file-in-any-of-the-roots))
5. Next error:

`Cannot read property 'ReactCurrentOwner' of undefined.`

6. I remove node_module, run npm install, yarn add react-navigation (If I use npm to install this module, I'll go back to the first erorr again). according to [this](https://github.com/chenglou/react-motion/issues/447).
7. Back to 1.
8. I give up and manually copy over my code to a new project.

This is incredibly frustrating. What am I doing wrong?

System Info:

- OS: OSX 10.12.6 Beta
- Simulator: iOS 10.3
- XCode: 8.3.3
- Node: 7.4.0
- Npm: 5.0.3
- React: 15.5.4
- React-Native: 0.45.0
- React-Native-Cli: 2.0.1

Comment: It seems to be a dependency issue. For some reason, my react version is set to 15.5.4 when it should be 16.0.0.alpha12.

Comment: This is a known issue with RN 0.45 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44413022/entry-point-for-packager/44415654#44415654

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so first, make sure you're in the correct directory. It sounds silly but it happens. You should be able to `ls` and see package.json.

If that's the case and it doesn't work, make sure you have react-native-cli installed globally. `npm install -g react-native-cli` You use `which react-native` to verify.

Next try killing the packager and xcode and restarting. Try running it again. If it doesn't work, kill xcode and the packager again, open the project with 'open ios/.xcodeproj', hit the run button and see if it works.

All in all I wouldn't reccomend using npm and yarn together. Stick with one or the other. I use npm.

The error `Cannot find entry file index.ios.js in any of the roots: ["/Users/Dan/ReactApp/node_modules/react-native/packager"`

Leads me to believe you're not in the correct directory.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that I'm in the right directory as its one of the first things I've read, and that I've had to go through this process 5 times today. With regards to yarn and npm, one of the packages doesn't install properly with npm for some reason. I'll try sticking with yarn.

Comment: If you do `npm start -- --reset-cache` it will work, but you need to do this every time. See https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14246. I assume RN will fix this next release as it's a pain.